# Is there any correction in new version of angular which is missing here?

Tags: angular

[error(2339)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q67I5.png)

As you see the in the image I face this problem while working with the latest version of angular and dependency injection , property declaration of angular

Comment: you write `[value]=['service']`. That means data you pass to value of input is an array, and array has not property formData. Please check your code again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.